# Saving image to device and using it in cordova-plugin-file-transfer returns ENCODING_ERR

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, android-image

I am trying to add a feature to an existing cordova plugin. The plugin doesn't allow to return an URI to a specific image, which is what I need. In order to do that, I have to create a local copy of the image. I have never worked with either Java on Android or cordova-plugins in general.

My changes seem to work fine. The file gets created and the plugin returns an URI to that file (in the form of `/data/app/cache/image.jpg`).

However, when I pass it to the cordova-plugin-file-transfer, I get an error: `FileError {code: 5, message: "ENCODING_ERR"}`. I found the error code here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings, but that doesn't really help me.

This is the code snippet that saves the file:

```
File outputDir = getContext().getCacheDir();

File outputFile = new File(outputDir, "cdvphotolibrary" + photoNameId);

try {
  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
  bos.write(photo.bytes);
  bos.flush();
  bos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
}

callbackContext.success(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/AndreasGassmann/cordova-plugin-photo-library/blob/nativeFileUrls/src/android/PhotoLibrary.java#L226

I read a lot of threads on Stackoverflow about saving images on Android, but they are not specific to Android and some of the solutions (like using ImageIO) don't work.

It would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I encountered this problem earlier when i was working on file and file transfer plugins. For some reason, the files will not be saved in cache directory even though it returns the URI. When i tried, it dint gave any error but also i couldnt see that file in the respective folder using file manager. So i went ahead with external directory approach. I read somewhere that writing in cache directory is possible only in rooted device. Not sure though. Check out this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations It might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I simply had to prepend `file://` to the string.

So in the end the URI was `file:///data/app/cache/image.jpg` and the file plugin was able to read it.